# Checking for pressed Enter button

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-10-universal

I already have a bunch of DelegateCommands in my Viewmodel. I want to implement a KeyDown/KeyUp event on some specific textbox. What I want is basically when the user pressed `Enter` button, the DelegateCommand will execute the contained codes. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Comment: What you have done so far? Please share your code and show at what point what you are trying to do? What you have tried so far?

Comment: I have already found a solution to this :D

Comment: Why you can't just simply call "ViewModel.MyCommand.Execute()" straight in the `TextBox_KeyDown` eventhandler?

Comment: @Fabio , I somehow cannot do it like that.

Comment: Ok, can you explain why. Sorry I am curios, I doing that way, because view always have reference of ViewModel.

Comment: Hi there @Fabio ,  I am sorry too.. Haha, when I said "somehow", it means, I am not sure why.. by the way, I have already found the alternative.. see my answer Edit 1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after playing, I have found the solution..

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            additem_button.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
        }
    }
//FocusState.Pointer as if the button was clicked by the user..
```

But this only work for PC tho. On mobiles, it will only closes the keyboard.

## Edit 1

Looks like I have found another solution, that can be used with MVVM :D

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            additem_button.Command.Execute("");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
// button.Command.Execute("your parameter"); because on my button, the
// command has been binded to a Delegate Command inside the VM :D
```

This will work on PC and mobiles..

Comment: Possibly, you want to check Command before executing: `if(additem_button.Command.CanExecute() == true) additem_button.Command.Execute();`

Comment: if you want a solution more generic and more reusable, you can make a Behavior to achieve that. With a unique behavior, you can bind any ICommand on any TextBox if you want.